# Getting data from all tables in a join query in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, join

I want to join tree tables and access the data from ALL of the tables and not only one.

The three tables are called: Page, Text, Image.

I tried with this but it did not work:

```
@texts = Page.joins([:texts, :images]).where(['pages.id = ?', @page])
```

The main one is Page which has_many texts and images. I want to do a query and get the data from all of them in one query. How is that possible in Rails 3? I cannot find a good example anywhere, not even in the official guides.

**Update**

The reason for doing this instead of @page.texts and @page.images is because I can then only print them in "blocks". I want to mix Texts and Images up when printed.

Comment: Are your three tables related via models, do you have associations setup between them?

Comment: Yes, in Page I got "has_many :text, :images" and in the Text and Image I got belongs_to :page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could make Text and Image subclasses of a new 'Page Element', so you can establish one relationship between page elements and your page.

On the other side, you can use `Page.join(:texts).select('texts.*')` and retrieve columns in the texts table as virtual columns of a Page objects (You could have a Page object with only virtual columns of other tables fields, so this solution can get dirty).

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

- Take a look at this page for help with joins. Notice the :include option which will allow you to get all the data in on query for performance's sake. You will still need to acess it though ActiveRecord (see below).

  http://www.railway.at/articles/2008/04/24/database-agnostic-database-ignorant/
- Do you need all the data in one giant hash/array? If you have associations setup you can simply do:

  `@texts = @page.texts` and `@images= @page.images`

**Edit**: What about this

```
@pages = Page.all(:include => [:texts, :images])
@pages.sort!{|a,b| a.texts.count <=> b.texts.count}
```

Documentation: http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M002186

Comment: Yes, this works fine, but the reason I need to get it in one query is so that I can order the items when printed. If I use @page.images and @page.texts I can only get them in "blocks" and not mix them up.

Comment: Thanks! But I not think that will help me. I cannot figure out why there are no documentation of this. I just want to get all the Texts and Images belonging to the Page in one query and be able to show them in the order of creation. Mix them up, so that there perhaps will be one textblock followed by an image and them another textblock. Is this not possible? It was simple in Codeigniter (PHP).

Answer (score -1):

This is worth a read, and will help to solve your problem:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: I have read it but I cannot get the code to work anyway. If you know how to do it please help!